# How to set up a Gluon application with Kotlin and Tornado FX

Tags: gradle, kotlin, gluon, tornadofx

I currently try to combine the following technologies:

- Gluon (Mobile)
- Gradle (dependency of Gluon, since they rely on it)
- Kotlin (because it's a nice language I want to dive into)
- Tornado FX (I guess it's for JavaFX, what Anko is for Android)

The issue is, that I'm relatively new to Intellij-IDEA and have issues setting it up properly, although I though, that the `build.gradle` file was appropriate enough.

Here's what my `build.gradle` looks so far:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.0.6'

    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:1.2.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

apply plugin: 'org.javafxports.jfxmobile'
apply plugin: 'kotlin'
// apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
// apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url 'http://nexus.gluonhq.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases'
    }
}

mainClassName = 'eu.dzim.test.Main'

dependencies {
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    // compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:$kotlin_version"
    compile 'com.gluonhq:charm:4.2.0'
    compile 'no.tornado:tornadofx:1.5.9'
    compile 'no.tornado:tornadofx-controls:1.0.4'
}

jfxmobile {
    downConfig {
        version = '3.1.0'
        // Do not edit the line below. Use Gluon Mobile Settings in your project context menu instead
        plugins 'display', 'lifecycle', 'statusbar', 'storage'
    }
    android {
        manifest = 'src/android/AndroidManifest.xml'
    }
}
```

I at lease managed to stop the IDE to complain about Kotlin. I converted a simple application class to look like this:

```
package eu.dzim.test

import com.gluonhq.charm.down.Platform
import javafx.application.Application
import javafx.scene.Scene
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane
import javafx.stage.Screen
import javafx.stage.Stage

/**
 * Created by daniel on 06.01.17.
 */
class Main : Application() {

    @Throws(Exception::class)
    override fun start(stage: Stage) {

        var width = -1.0
        var height = -1.0
        if (Platform.isDesktop()) {
            width = 480.0
            height = 640.0
            stage.title = "Test"
        }
        val primaryScreen = Screen.getPrimary()
        val visualBounds = primaryScreen.visualBounds
        if (width < 0 || height < 0) {
            width = visualBounds.width
            height = visualBounds.height
        }

        val root = BorderPane()

        val scene = Scene(root, width, height)

        stage.scene = scene

        stage.show()
    }
}
```

But now I'm stuck, because the dependency to Tornado FX is not resolved properly.
I wanted to create a `View` and started with

```
package eu.dzim.test

import tornadofx.View
import tornadofx.borderpane

class Root : View("My View") {
    override val root = borderpane {

    }
}
```

But the imports like `import tornadofx.View` never get resolved.

Is there an issue, because Tornado seems to use Kotlin `1.0.5`, while I want to use `1.0.6`? (Although this has no effect, if I change it, regarding the (still unused, because "unresolved") `View`...)

Regards,
Daniel

Comment: I tried your exact build file with no modifications, and I was able to import it into IDEA without issues. Can you try to run "gradle build" from the command line to see if this is merely an IDEA issue or something else?

Comment: The funny thing is: from the console it both build and started. But the IDE insisted, it was not properly set up and could not use Kotlin and Tornado out-of-the-box...

Comment: @edvin so you have some other plugins, libraries, etc. already set up prior to the import? I started with a fresh installation of IDEA and needed to convert the original Java to Kotlin. And there the issues started.

Comment: No, I did not. Can you try to close the IDEA project, remove the .idea folder, then import the project again?

Comment: @EdvinSyse I did as you suggested. And to my surprise: it works. I guess IDEA was just confused when I updated the existing project step by step. And (from a developer perspective) there is one thing I would need to do: move the Kotlin files to _/src/main/kotlin_ (currently still in _/src/main/java_). Can you create an answer, I could up-vote and set the tick? Thanks. PS: One issue I detected with __TornadoFX__, when I finally could work with it: It seems to be not compatible with Android (I guess some Java8-interna, not provided by Google).

Comment: Great, I'll add an answer :)

Comment: TornadoFX requires JavaFX 8.0, and therefore Java 8, so it can't be used with Kotlin as you pointed out :)

Comment: This is a pity. :-D Are there any plans for a "Android-Version", so that I could use it in JavaFXPorts like you can use Anko? Nevertheless: Thanks for you help, it was greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like something went wrong when IDEA analyzed the build file and generated invalid metadata, probably due to incremental changes to your build config. To regenerate the metadata, do the following

- Close IDEA
- Remove the .idea folder inside the project folder
- Import the project

This time the metadata would be generated from the already complete build file and it should be set up correctly.

Also note that the Kotlin plugin by default will compile Kotlin sources in `src/main/kotlin`. Either change the source folder or konfigure the Kotlin plugin to compile sources in `src/main/java`:

```
sourceSets {
    main.kotlin.srcDirs += 'src/main/java'
}
```